# Horizontally and vertically scrolling table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, scrollview

I am trying to create a table view that scrolls horizontally and vertically like TeacherKit app. 
If I scroll vertically, first row is fixed and if I scroll horizontally, first column is fixed. 
Do you guys have any suggestions for that?
This is the screenshot from TeacherKit app.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/65cknxg9vnea8jq/Photo%20Nov%2015%2C%2012%2027%2010%20AM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common solution is to create a UIScrollView with the same size of your UITableview, and place your table INSIDE the scroll view.

In this situation, the table won't scroll because is fully contained in the scrollView (it has the same size) and you will scroll the scrollView

Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Thank you sir, I will try it out, then will let you know.

Comment: Cool, if you have any doubts post it, and if it works mark it as resolved